# Python convert string to float

Tags: python, string

I have a string that looks like this:

```
a = "'92.345'\r\n\r\n"
a.strip()
```

When I try to convert it into float using `np.float(a)` or just `float(a)`, I get

```
*** Value error: could not convert string to float: '92.345'
```

How do I convert it cleanly to a float?

Comment: What do you think would `\r` or `\n` become when converted to a float?

Comment: sorry, I did use strip as well, but that does not help

Comment: edited question to reflect use of strip

Comment: It's probably worth noting that `a.strip()` on its own does nothing. You have to do something with the result, ex. `a = a.strip()` or `x = float(a.strip())` or whatever.

Comment: how do you get such a string?

Comment: @Kevin sorry, I did do that, just did not post it here

Comment: @Daniel, getting it from a netcdf file. Using the nco tools to read it. Invoking nco tool through subprocess call in windows

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [strip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) your string to remove the whitespaces and one quote `'`:

```
>>> float(a.strip().strip("'"))
92.345
```

Or as @Martijn Pieters says in comment you can use use `a.strip("\r\n\t '")` to reduce this to one strip call.

Comment: or use `a.strip("\r\n\t '")` to reduce this to *one* strip call.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `str.translate`:

```
print(float(a.translate(None,"\r\n'")))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try slicing the string to extract only the digit part of it:

```
a = "'92.345'\r\n\r\n"
x = float(a[1:6])
```

Comment: The only issue with this is it can't do it again and again, you need to know what you are slicing before hand.

Answer (score 1):

Remove everything but digit and dot

```
>>> a = "'92.345123'\r\n\r\n"
>>> float(re.sub(r'[^0-9\.]', '', a))
92.345123
```