# How to convert strings in a list to floats

Tags: python-3.x

I have this list:

```
array = ['Katherine', '999', '333']
```

I need to convert the `'999'` and `'333'` into floats.

The list should look like this after:

```
array = ['Katherine', 999.0, 333.0]
```

Comment: So convert them, `float(str)` converts a string to a float.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert string to float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219479/python-convert-string-to-float)

Comment: I improved the formatting of your question to make it easier to read. Please review Stack Overflow's formatting documentation in the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) so you can do this yourself next time. Good luck!

Comment: What you have is a list. You will help yourself learning Python if you use the right names for the things you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `float(s)` can do this. Here is the code.

```
array = ['Katherine', '999', '333']

def is_number(s):
    """ Returns True if the string is a number. """
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print(array)

// for i, v in enumerate(array):
//     if is_number(v):
//         array[i] = float(v)

array = list(map(is_number, array))

print(array)
```

Comment: Better yet, have `is_number` return the float value *if possible* or the original value otherwise (and rename the function to `try_parse` or something like that). All that remains to be done then is: `array = list(map(try_parse, array))`.